# Can't open cursor lib 'libodbccr'

Tags: php, pdo, unixodbc, mdbtools, centos6.5

I'm trying to connect to a .mdb file, and installed MDBTools

When I run the PHP script this is the error I get;

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open cursor lib 'libodbccr'
```

Under `/usr/lib64` I find the following similar libs;

- libodbccr.so.2
- libodbccr.so.2.0.0

Is there a configuration file I need to edit, because to me it seems like the lib is there, just that unixODBC cant find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little searching around I came across a solution, apparently there is a but in CentOS.

This fixed the problem for me;

```
sudo ln /usr/lib64/libodbccr.so.2 /usr/lib64/libodbccr.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Debian 11 the solution was

```
sudo apt-get install php-odbc libodbc1 php-odbc mdbtools
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.1 /etc/libodbccr.so
```